# Effects of not sleeping at night

Tags: sleep, sleep-deprivation, lasting-effects-duration, benefits, insomnia

I have got some exams coming up, and I am kinda short on time. So, I am planning to stay up for a couple of nights for studying. What effects will this have(both positive and negative). Thanks

Comment: not good idea before exams

Answer (score 1):

1. Increased risk of disease.
2. Heightened blood pressure.
3. Weakened immune system and reduced effectiveness of certain vaccinations.
4. Stress.
5. Greater risk of death.
6. Impaired creativity.
7. Moodiness.
8. Lower GPA.
9. Poor decisions.
10. Twitchy eyes.
11. Fertility issues.
12. Sex drought.
13. Weight gain.
14. Fat Gene activation.
15. Emotional eating.
16. Depression.
17. Increased risk of car accidents.
18. Slower reaction time.
19. Tired partner.
20. Tremors.
21. Premature aging.
22. Dry skin.
23. Big-time breakouts.
24. Dull skin.
25. Skin sensitivity.

More detail :

1. http://www.cosmopolitan.com/health-fitness/advice/a34370/terrible-side-effects-of-skimping-on-sleep-in-your-20s/
2. http://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/features/10-results-sleep-loss#1
3. http://www.healthline.com/health/sleep-deprivation/effects-on-body